# From InputStream to parallel Stream<T>

Tags: java, java-stream

I am getting an InputStream that contains multiple elements, they are scanned, parsed, iterated by a Stream in a serial way (same order they had in the `InputStream`), and then persisted in a DB. This works fine.

Now, I am trying to iterate the Stream in parallel way, with `Stream<T>.parallel()`, so while one thread is blocked persisting, other ones can still scanning the InputStream and persisting.

Then, I tried to parallelized the resulting `Stream<MyElement>` with `Stream<T>.parallel()`. To check that the parallelization works, I added into the stream a map function that add a random delay. I was expecting that the resulted elements were printed in a random order.

But the result is not the expected one. The elements are still shown in the file order.

Is there a way to properly iterate this stream in parallel?

```
public class FromInputStreamToParallelStream {    

    public static Stream<MyElement> getStream(InputStream is) {
        try (var scanner = new Scanner(is)) {
            return scanner//
                    .useDelimiter("DELIMITER")
                    .tokens()
                    .parallel() 
                    .map(MyElementParser::parse);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException  {
        try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("my-file.xml"));) {
            getStream(in)
                    .map(FromInputStreamToParallelStream::sleepRandom) 
                    .forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }

    private static MyElement sleepRandom(MyElement element) {
        var randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(10);
        System.out.println("wait. " + randomNumber);

        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(randomNumber);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return element;
    }
}
```

I guess I gonna need to implement my own `Spliterator<T>`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An `InputStream`? No. See the implementation of `Files.lines()`, which supports parallel streaming on how they do that.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I can't stream directly the file just line by line. I need to split by a deliminator and parse into MyElement, then I would have my Stream<MyElement>. A MyElement can be serialized in n-lines in the file.

Comment: Yeah, I suggested you take a look at how that is done (it's not trivial), not to use it.

Comment: The `InputStream` detour is unnecessary, you can use `new Scanner(Paths.get("my-file.xml"))` to create the Scanner. Further, `Files.lines(…)` is the wrong pointer, especially the `BufferedReader.lines()` implementation shows how *not* to do it. Since you’re operation is based on a `Scanner` (the right tool for the job), `Scanner.tokens()` is the right pointer. When you are using Java 9 or newer, you can directly use `new Scanner(Paths.get("my-file.xml")) .useDelimiter(DELIMITER).tokens().map(Parser::parse)` and you have your Stream. Otherwise, look at how it has been implemented

Comment: @Holger Nice, with Scanner.tokens() I could get rid of a lot boilerplate code, but the stream doesn't run in parallel yet.

Comment: It’s difficult to parallelize an operation starting with a sequential data source, in general. But it could do better in the reference implementation, as it is known to deal badly with unknown stream sizes. You can give it a try by copying the implementation of `tokens()` and replace the `Long.MAX_VALUE`, which stands for “unknown size”, with the file size, which can serve as a reasonable estimate, as there can’t be more matches than characters (in fact, the reference implementation copes better with unreasonable estimates than “unknown size”).